# To find maximal linearly independent subset of an infinite subset of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a maximal linearly independent set in the following subset $C$ of $$\Bbb R^{k+1}:C= \{ (1,t,t^2,t^3,\ldots,t^k): t \in \Bbb R\}~,$$ where $k$ is an integer and $k \ge$ 1.

**Please tell me if my approach below is correct.**

Consider the $n+1$ vectors obtained by putting $t = 1,2,3, \ldots ,k+1$. Now we construct a matrix with these vectors as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1& \cdots &\cdots&1\\
1&2&2^2&2^3&2^4& \cdots & \cdots &2^k\\
1&3&3^2& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &  &3^k\\
\vdots & \vdots &&&&& \ddots& \vdots\\
1&(k+1)&(k+1)^2& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &(k+1)^k\end{bmatrix}_{(k+1)\text{by}(k+1)}$$

Now we consider the columns of this matrix.
My claim that the columns are linearly independent which implies the vectors i have chosen are linearly independent.

Denote the columns as $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_{k+1}$.
Let there be $k+1$ real scalars $\beta_1,\beta_2, \ldots,\beta_{k+1}$ such that 
    $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i\beta_i = \theta$$

Then the new vector on LHS is $$\begin{aligned}
\bigl( &\beta_1 + \beta_2 \cdot 1 +\beta_3 \cdot 1^2 + \dotsb + \beta_{k+1} \cdot 1^k, \\
&\beta_1 + \beta_2 \cdot 2 +\beta_3 \cdot 2^2 + \dotsb + \beta_{k+1} \cdot 2^k, \\
&\hspace{36pt}\vdots  \\
&\beta_1 + \beta_2 \cdot (k+1)+ \dotsb + \beta_{k+1} \cdot (k+1)^k \bigr) \end{aligned}$$
We see that each component of this vector is equal to $0$ which tells me that the polynomial of degree $k$
$$\beta_1 + \beta_2 \cdot t +\beta_3 \cdot t^2 + \dotsb + \beta_{k+1} \cdot t^k$$
has $k+1$ distinct zeros.

This means that the polynomial must be zero hence all the scalars must be zero and hence the column vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Maximal LI subset is basis of C

Comment: Where did you find this problem? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: you may want to check Vandermonde matrices and their properties (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

Comment: Yes vandermonde matrix makes the proof easier .